# Getting opaque submission error when putting a `mailto:` in code part of question

Tags: bug, asking-questions

My question I had problems submitting is here:

[What are the valid characters in the domain part of e-mail address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002279/what-are-the-valid-characters-in-the-domain-part-of-e-mail-address)

The submit button gave me an opaque error when I had this line in my question:

```
mailto:<uri-encoded local part>@<domain part>
```

It doesn't matter what sort of code tag I stuck it in, I still got an error.

Preferably I'd at least get some indication of what the error was, and ideally I could submit this and any escaping that needed to happen would happen on the server side.

The error I am getting looks like this:

[image]

This happens both on initial submit and on subsequent edits (as the screenshot shows).

Interestingly enough, it doesn't happen on meta, as I just submitted this bug report with no problems!

Comment: Looks like an overeager filter. It shouldn't block that when it's in a code block.

Comment: Heh, the response is actually an Internal Server Error, so this definitely seems like a [meta-tag:bug] ;).

Comment: Most likely something on your end.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - or it might have been fixed in the one year interval ;)