# An error occurred submitting the answer

Tags: bug, answers

Trying to post the text in the text file located here (shortened Skydrive URL) http://sdrv.ms/16Q10JW

to this question:

[Keep "Backspace" key from being held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219434/keep-backspace-key-from-being-held-down)

I've tried deleting different portions of the code, replacing tabs with spaces, removing the ellipses in some of the code blocks...but it won't go through.

The `submit` post always lasts for a couple minutes and then aborts

Comment: You mean you have internet/network issues?

Comment: I am not sure of the issue, but I edited your deleted answer and placed your code in it without any issues.  Feel free to undelete it now

Comment: Network is fine; I've been able to post answers without code blocks. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: A possibly similar issue is [reported here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183642/145673)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I tried simplifying chunks of code and getting rid of anything that looked slightly unusual to no avail. Oh well, I undeleted it; thanks bluefeet